# iOS Storyboard ViewController went Blank

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on the code in a project when I suddenly notice the ViewController in Storyboards is greyed out with the name of the VC in the center.

Here's a screenshot..

[image]

I was only editing some code on the right and I'm not sure exactly when, but my eyes adjusted and noticed this VC completely greyed out in Storyboards.

I tried deleting Derived Data, cleaning, quitting Xcode, building again, etc.

Nothing seems to work... ANy help with this would be super appreciated. I'm also very new to programming in general.

Comment: Why you instantiate the same viewcontroller(LoginVC) inside `didLoad:` & login button action? Also a func named `showLoginVC`

Comment: It's hard to help you when you can't give us anything to duplicate. If I may be a bit critical? I counted no less than 7 view controllers in your project, along with a single storyboard. It appears you are using a split screen and... editing code? Don't. Xcode can be... touchy in my experience. The *only* time IMHO you want this kind of split screen is is you are *connecting* `IBOutlets` and/or `IBActions`. If you wish to be *"editing some code"* do it **without** having a storyboard (long ago called Interface Builder) open on screen. There's no reason for that!

Comment: @LalKrishna - A really dumb error... I fixed it to HomeVC as it's supposed to be. And the last one showLoginVC was something I was playing with to test different ways of accomplishing the task and considering the different needs I may have for the transition.

Comment: @dfd - Thanks, you most definitely can be critical! I appreciate the tips A LOT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it turns out if you ever run into this problem, it's because you're not paying close attention and haven't realized you've somehow magically deleted your entire view inside the ViewController.

I did this once before by hitting something randomly on my keyboard (don't know what it was) but that time I saw it happen and just hit "undo".

This time I was passed the point of simply hitting "undo" and had to add a view again and rebuild and reconnect all the components in the view. That was basically it. Problem solved...